# Android ActionBar actionBarSize (bar height) does not work in Portrait Mode

Tags: android-actionbar, portrait

To briefly explain my goal : I'm building an app to a public terminal on android. I'm trying to avoid the top finger pull Status/Notification Menu by the android os. I have not been able to prevent this Menu mechanism programmatically. To accomplish this goal, I'll have a custom made enclosure that'll cover top part of the screen for the android device. Enclosure will also cover home, back buttons.

I'm using android ActionBar (not Sherlock). Obviously the ActionBar tabs needs to move down a little to make room for the covered part by the enclosure. I set paddings for the actionbar through Theming.
Here is corresponding part of /res/values/themes.xml (AndroidManifest.xml is already set to use CustomTheme)

```
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>  
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_default_height</item>   
  </style>
  <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/actionbar_paddingtop</item>
  </style>
```

This works as expected in landscape mode. In portrait mode paddingtop will work, but action bar height will not adjust (actionBarSize don't work), so the ActionBar tab text will get cut off.

At first I tought dimen files could be the problem. I've tried generating /res/values-port copies of themes.xml and dimens.xml, but doesn't seem to be the problem. padding works after all. I've also tried putting in direct values like 90dp for actionBarSize, and 32dp for padding without any luck.

To me it appears portrait mode does not like actionBarSize. There is no similar question on the web related to this issue, maybe I'm missing something simple. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be already too late to answer your question. I will just put this here.

Apparently, this is a bug from android sdk, check this link.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41792